# Wacom Bamboo CTH-470K left handed

Tags: wacom, bamboo

Just got my CTH-470K which works excellently on Ubuntu. However, I want to use it left handed. That is to say that I want to turn it around 180 degrees so that up is down and left is right. There is a setting for this in the Wacom device settings, but it only seems to change for the pen, not the touch usage.

I want to set this for both pen and touch. Thanks. Martin